# Cumulative totals in 2 columns and difference between them (DAX)

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have my data structured like this (extracted from SQL) of people taking the bus in one section and getting off in another (or the same):

```
Track  Direction  Hour  Passengers  Section In   Section Out
1175     Going     6        1           1              4
1175     Going     6        1           2              5
1175     Going     7        1           1              4
1175     Going     8        1           1              4
1175     Going     12       1           2              5
...      ...       ...      ...         ...           ...
```

I need the following 3 tables to be dynamic so I can apply filters:

[image]

My biggest problem is how to do the filter context in the TOTAL table because I have 2 columns of sections (Section In and Section Out). I don't know how to combine them or create a new one so I can have the expected result in a pivot table.

Also the the TOTAL table should calculate the Maximun value instead of doing the difference of the other 2 tables.

Ask me if you need more details. Here is the the data so you can test a possible solution. Thank you!

[Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eTZBgFzq1Ri4dv9qxhs0w8h5S2esXLEf)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use pivot tables?

- If yes, you could simply do the MAX calculation in the table, instead of the difference (for section 1 and 2, =MAX(B5,G5)). The inconvenience of this is that you need to update both "in" and "out" filters to update the MAX result. Better to get an alert if the numbers don't match (for example (B1=G1) would give you FALSE if filters are different)
- If you are not too fussed about using pivot tables: I would advise to get these results using formulas directly. In the image below, I am proposing a solution with simple SUMIFS to get the number of passengers for the line and section. The table is simpler than multiple Pivot Tables, easier to format etc. And you can get the "filter" function by doing data validation based on the de-duplicated list of bus lines
  *EDIT - you can add more filters too, for example on the hours, see updated image*
- *Also, for a quick check, for example just other your data table you can directly put dynamic sums, using the SUBTOTAL(9,...) formula: it will only count the displayed values*

Hope this helps!
Cheers

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you answer! Your approach is very insteresting but is not the solution I'm looking for because each track or bus line has different sections. So, If I create a table with formulas it will be static, i.e. with 5 sections, and if I filter it with another track it may have 7 sections... I don't know if that could work with this dynamic scenario.

I know the scenario is a bit complex because of the 2 section columns and how to combine them in only 1. I think is a matter of filter context but for real, I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Also, the track is not the only filter I may have. I may filter this by hour or another descriptive field. In that scenario, the SUMIFS would be a bit complex right? For example, how to filter it to see the passengers between 6 and 10 (hour)?

Comment: You're welcome. Well again, various options.
- As mentioned you can use the MAX function in your table, it is the easiest to do, probably the most flexible for multiple filtering, but not the "cleanest" if I may say, and as you mentioned it could bring issues if you are filtering 2 different bus lines.
- I have updated my post above to show you how you could add filters on hours as well in the case you would use SUMIFS. (Formula to be adjusted for different track lines on IN and OUT)
- Third option (or more probably a complement) is to use the subtotal function directly on the data table

Comment: Also - to solve the issue of the different number of sections for each track, you could add lines with 0 passengers for all your lines, sections and hours. That would be a bit annoying to do but would solve your issue of the different size of pivot tables without changing your result on the nuber of passengers

Comment: Hi Céline! Thanks again for the heads up on this!! Your idea is pretty cool. Besides is not the solution I was looking for or imagined, is a solution. I will leave the topic open for a while so maybe someone else could give their opinion here to solve it with DAX and M. I think is a scenario that could be useful for more people. Thank you very much again!!